# How to open terminal remotely with C scripting

Tags: c

This project consists of a server (victim - Debian) and a client (attacker - Kali). The server is a program running in a loop and listening on a port.
It receives messages across the network from the client. Each message must correspond to a system command to be executed.
Each message must correspond to a system command to be executed. Once executed, the server sends a message to the client with
the result of the executed command.

The client is another program that the attacker will
run at will.

I've tried this;

Server side (debian):

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
        int sockid;
        int port = 1254;
        char *ip = "192.168.0.42";

        sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0); //paramètre du socket
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

        char *buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n, len;
        int bind_result = bind(sockid, (const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

        if(bind_result<0)
        {
                printf("Erreur durant la liaison de l'IP au socket\n");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Ecoute sur %s:%d\n", ip, port);
                len = sizeof(client_addr);
                n = recvfrom(sockid, (char *)buffer, BUFFER_SIZE,
                        MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr,&len);
                printf("Message de taille %d envoyé par [%s:%d]: %s\n",n, inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), client_addr.sin_port, buffer);

        }
        close(sockid);

}
```

On the client (kali):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        int sockid;
        int port = 1254;
        char *ip = "192.168.0.42";

        sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);

        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

        char *msg = "Salutation serveur ! ceci est un message test";
//      char *const argv[] = {"/bin/sh", 0};
//      execve("/bin/sh", argv, 0);

        sendto(sockid, (const char *)msg, strlen(msg), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));

//      return 0;
        close(sockid);
}
```

With this code, I can send a message to my server or open a shell but locally (with the commented code).

But I want to send "Open terminal" to my server, to be able to use the command from my Kali — in two words, a **reverse shell**.

Comment: Q: do you expect this "terminal" to be visible from a remote connection?  And if it's not "visible" ... then why do you need a "terminal" in the first place?  What exactly is the "goal" you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: So you want to do something like `ssh`, but much unsafer and ripe for exploits?

Comment: @paulsm4 I just want to be able to read the response of that terminal, and its for a school project but i dont know where to start sooo i'm asking for help x), i need to gather information of the Debian.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude Well yes we can say that (i only want to gather information like the hostname or the ip, i dont want to use exploit)

Comment: You want to have a generic way of sending commands and translating/forwarding them to the shell on the target, and feedback the response of the shell-command as a response. This type of communication is called Remote Procedure Call (RPC, sometimes RFC) and there are defined standards (e.g. [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/)).

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as a C "script". C is a compiled language (in contrast to interpreter languages like Shell)

Comment: Is the server on a POSIX (e.g. Linux or macOS)? Then I recommend you first take some time to learn about pipes, processes, and the `exec` family of commands. After that remember tat on POSIX systems a socket is just like any other descriptor, and can in fact be used like a pair of pipes.

Comment: @gkhaos ok so i'll start my research on RPC / RFC, yeah sorry for the "script" its a bad habit in french

Comment: @someprogrammerdude my server is on Linux (debian), guess i'm back to the doc

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a command remotely, you'd typically use [ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).  You don't need to do any socket programming to use ssh.

If you can use ssh, then you should. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel.  And using ssh is far more secure!

It sounds like this is a class assignment. You need to write a socket "listener" that executes some remote command and returns the command's output.  If so, you probably want your socket to call [popen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

Here's a simple "popen()" example:

> https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1418
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>     FILE *p;
>     int ch;
>
>     p = popen("ver","r");   /* DOS */
> /*  p = popen("uname","r"); /* Unix */
>     if( p == NULL)
>     {
>         puts("Unable to open process");
>         return(1);
>     }
>     while( (ch=fgetc(p)) != EOF)
>         putchar(ch);
>     pclose(p);
>
>     return(0);
> }
> ```

To clarify the usual meanings of "server" and "client":

- **Server**: waits for commands, executes them, returns a response.
- **Client**: sends a command to the server, waits for the server's response.

You absolutely don't need to programmatically "open a terminal" for any of this.

### Addendum

Regarding the requirements for the class assignment:

> This project consists of a server (victim - debian) and a client (attacker - kali). the server is a program running in a loop and listening on an port. It receives messages across the network from the client. Each message must correspond to a system command to be executed. Each message must correspond to a system command to be executed. Once executed, the server sends a message to the client with the result of the executed command.

Easy peasy.  You're almost there:

- You'll need to modify your server to [listen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html), then [accept()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) new requests, and handle them in a loop.
- Your server could use [popen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to execute the requested command, and write the results back to the client.  Forget about "opening a terminal".
- Your client is sending OK.  Now you need modify it to read the results back from the server.

Here's some example code: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/ (there are many, many examples on Google)

You might also be interested in [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: You're right its a class assignement, but how do i send command if i don't open a shell before ?
So the popen is used to launch another program while running the code, and with that i can say "when server receive connection from client --> play this command on terminal --> send the result to client"


Guess i have some other research to do on popen.

Comment: i read the website you linked, but i don't understand this part,
p = popen("uname","r");
i have to replace "uname" with "cmd" or with the command i want to play on the server ?
If its the second it doesn't work for me because i need to send multiple command on the server (and the shell need to be active, i can't restart the program over and over again), that's why i thought i needed to "open a terminal".
 i don't know if i'm clear... english is not my native language, i'm sorry

Comment: Here i copied the statement of the assignement

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! i'll check all the links you just send and i'll be back with a solution !  thanks for all the advices everyone

Comment: Hello @paulsm4, just to let you know i found a way to play command on a remote host ! Do have any idea of how can i send the result of the command to the client ?